# SQL Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I do not get what I am missing here. To me it seems like I included every non-aggregate value in the select statement

```
SELECT TOP 5
    f_ev2.Identifier,
    AVG(f_ev2.Identifier) AS Identifier,
    MIN(f_ev2.Event_dtm) AS Erster_PZ_Scan
FROM DB_DWH_MART_AKM_PLT.VW_F_EVENT f_ev2
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
        DISTINCT f_ev.AUFTRAGGEBER_EKP AS EKP
        FROM    DB_DWH_MART_AKM_PLT.VW_F_EVENT f_ev
        WHERE f_ev.PROCESS_NO = 1075
    ) AS manifest_users
ON f_ev2.AUFTRAGGEBER_EKP = manifest_users.EKP
WHERE f_ev2.event_dtm BETWEEN (date -1) AND  (date -10)
GROUP BY f_ev2.Identifier
HAVING (f_ev2.PROCESS_NO = 1 OR f_ev2.PROCESS_NO = 2)
```

Why do I get

```
SQL Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group
```

Comment: A `HAVING` is normally used for the aggregation functions like AVG, MIN.  Hence, the criteria on PROCESS_NO should be in the WHERE clause.  Also, do you think this makes sense : `SELECT x, AVG(x) FROM t GROUP BY x`

Comment: @LukStorms you are right, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After* aggregation there's no more detail, i.e. `f_ev2.PROCESS_NO`.

You can either move the condition to WHERE

```
AND f_ev2.PROCESS_NO IN (1, 2)
```

or apply an aggregate function, e.g.

```
HAVING MIN(f_ev2.PROCESS_NO IN (1, 2)
```

But following condition will always return an empty result set, Explain will reveal an *unsatisfiable condition*:

```
WHERE f_ev2.event_dtm BETWEEN (date -1) AND  (date -10)
```

You must switch the dates:

```
WHERE f_ev2.event_dtm BETWEEN (current_date -10) AND  (current_date -1)
```

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to GROUP the query for example two values like 2 and 3 together and make a seperate listing for value 4?

Comment: Do you mean `select case when col IN (2,3) then '2/3'  when col = 4 then '4' end as grp .... group by grp`?

Comment: yes, that would be one possibility